# How to print the pipe output in Hadoop cascading

Tags: java, hadoop, cascading

I have big query(SAS report) and converting that query into cascading flow. Just for debugging purpose, i like to print each pipe output using logger or system.out.println.

Please suggest me how to do this in hadoop cascading tool.

Thanks,
Saravanan

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Maybe take a look at ["How do I ask good Questions"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show that you’ve already put some effort into solving your problem.

Comment: The preferred approach is [Checkpoint](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.0/javadoc/cascading/pipe/Checkpoint.html), not println. Here's an example: [Cascading for the Impatient, Part 6](http://www.cascading.org/2012/08/07/cascading-for-the-impatient-part-6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
pipe = new Each(pipe, new Debug("displayText", true));
```

true is used to display header in data. Set it to false if you do not want header info.
With this, you will see every line of data in pipe with the column name [visit here](https://ramzavil.wordpress.com/2016/10/23/cascading-1-intro-creating-a-flow/)